# Mac Mail receiving emails extremely slowly

Tags: macbook-pro, mail.app, email

I recently purchased my first rMBP and I have noticed that Mail receives emails extremely slow. I receive the email on my iPhone 10 - 15 minutes before it appears on Mail.

I've tried searching for solutions however it doesn't seem like this is a problem many are having. Anyone have any solutions?

Comment: the iPhone's email populates by "push" which means as soon as the server gets it, you will be notified. The Mac's email is "pulled" at a timed interval as Buscar웃SD mentions below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mail there is a Activity view. Turn it on and see what is happening.

It looks like this

[image: activity]

All the bars should disappear with in a 1-2 minutes.

Also check in the Mail preferences the setting for how frequently to check for Mail. Hope it is not set on 15 minutes but more frequently.

[image: get mail]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the [IDLE command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2177) is selected in Mail > Preferences > Accounts > Account in question > Advanced", if supported by your server.
It's not the same as 'Push', but can speed up Mail delivery.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider clearing or archiving folders where mail is automatically being placed.

After trying many things (like clobbering old directories in Caches, Preferences and Containers) with only minimal benefit, I had some success by clearing out some subfolders that I don't pay much attention to, where I have less-important mail refiled by server-side rules.

When those folders had around 10K messages in them, I saw mail get stuck "Downloading messages" forever, not pull in incoming Mail for hours (until restart), or simply crash occasionally.  I haven't seen any of those since clearing out that clutter, knock on wood.